# Line spacing 1 1/2 means how much in web development?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a client requirement to set line space to 1 1/2 (1.5). It's for setting line-height while creating PDF through PHP, and the PDF is a court document (US).

I am not a designer guy, and I am unable to understand the requirement. If some could help me to understand the requirement it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: `but am not getting understand what client says and the problem is client is not technical guy` You should hire a translator then...

Comment: You might get better answers on some other stackexchange website.

Comment: If you're creating a PDF then you need to be dealing in PDF terms, not in standard web terms. (They might be the same for all I know, but all the answers your are getting are talking about HTML/CSS, not PDF).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the 1.5 is 1.5x line-height.

Refer to the [line-height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) property in CSS.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a document requirement ... that there be space between lines, like setting line spacing in MS Word.

The comparable in HTML/css would be CSS setting: `line-height`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height